# Python Pandas Simple Moving Average (deprecated pd.rolling_mean)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to retrieve some stock data and calculates SMAs etc. Since the function rolling_mean has been deprecated in Pandas, I tried Series instead. However, I get an error message: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 6 to array axis with dimension 2165

Could anyone tell me what I do wrong?

Many thanks!

```
import numpy as np  # array operations
import pandas as pd  # time series management
from pandas_datareader import data as web  # data retrieval
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # standard plotting library
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()  # nicer plotting style

import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)

end = datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 19)
f = web.DataReader('F', 'morningstar', start, end)
print(f.tail)

f['SMA50'] = pd.rolling_mean(f['Close'], window=50) #OLD

f['SMA50'] = pd.Series(f).rolling(window=50).mean() #NEW
```

Comment: It is just `f['Close'].rolling(window=50).mean()`  You don't need the series constructor.

Comment: duh!! many thanks man!

Comment: I am redirecting this to a more detailed answer since your issue is resolved.

Comment: In case you are still around, can I pester you with a follow up question? I try to pull in multiple instruments but only the first works, getting NaNs for the rest.. Would appreciate if you still have a moment for me :)                symbols = ['MSFT', 'YHOO', 'AMZN', 'GOOG']  # our symbols
data = pd.DataFrame()  # empty DataFrame


for sym in symbols:
    data[sym] = web.DataReader(sym, data_source='morningstar')['Close']
    
print(data.tail)

Comment: `web.DataReader` returns a MultiIndex DataFrame so your indices do not match when you iteratively assign a new column. Try `data[sym] = web.DataReader(sym, data_source='morningstar')['Close'].reset_index(level='Symbol', drop=True)` (This will get rid of the first level of the index, namely Symbol, since you already have that as a column).

Comment: mate, youre a star! many many thanks. have a great weekend!